# How to set `lookup_field` correctly for `HyperlinkedIdentityField` in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to change default `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` urls. According to documentation, I have to either define `url` field manually like this:

**serializers.py**

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='stock-detail', lookup_field='unique_id')

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['id', 'url', 'symbol', 'unique_id', 'other_details']
```

Or use `extra_kwargs` like this:

**serializers.py**

```
class StockSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Stock
        fields = ['id', 'url', 'symbol', 'unique_id', 'other_details']
        extra_kwargs = {
            'url': {'view_name': 'stock-detail', 'lookup_field': 'unique_id'}
        }
```

But non of them work for me. The error is:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "stock-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

This is my `views.py`:

```
class StockViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
```

And if I change `lookup_field` to `pk` (in serializers.py), it work without any errors but urls are not what I want. So how can I set `lookup_field` correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporarily fixed the problem by changing `unique_id` field in `models.py` to become `primary_key=True`, so that `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` automatically uses `unique_id` to create urls.

But the question still remains: How to make `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` to use other fields than `pk` to create urls?

**EDIT**: Permanently fixed the problem by adding `lookup_field = 'unique_id'` to `views.py` and `serializers.py`.